# meaning of "|=" in swift programming?

Tags: swift

I'm have a sample code

```
slide |= self.options.rightPanFromBezel && self.isRightPointContainedWithinBezelRect(point)
```

That someone could explain to me the meaning of `|=` in swift programming.

Thank!

Comment: It *is* documented in the official Swift book from Apple, under "Binary expressions": *`|=` Bitwise OR and assign* .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this operator is almost the same as specifying

```
slide = slide | self.options.rightPanFromBezel && self.isRightPointContainedWithinBezelRect(point)
```

, except that result is only evaluated once.

The |= operator coerces the arguments to matching data types. Then the |= operator looks at the binary representation of the values of result and expression and does a bitwise OR operation on them.

You can check more operators here [swift operators - nshipster](http://nshipster.com/swift-operators/)

Comment: there is no "except". They are equivalent. It doesn't count as binary operator, it's an assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

It is a 'compound assignment operator'. It is used in many languages, and a brother of the often seen `+=` and `-=`:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators

Loosely speaking, it will set `slide` to `true` if it was already `true` or if the expression to the right side of `|=` is `true`.

Comment: Speaking about `true` and `false` with binary operators (not logical operators) is wrong.

Comment: That's why I said 'loosely'. From the sample code, it is clear we're talking about booleans here.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Saw `options` and was thinking about integers.